# Should "migration" comments be flagged post-migration

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags, migrated-questions

A lot of times, when someone asks a Meta question on the main site, it will attract comments that say something along the lines of:

> This question belongs on Meta [...]

It seems that once the questions gets migrated, above comments still remain on the migrated question. Should we flag the comments as *No longer neccesary* or just let them be?

Comment: I would go with flagging because the question has been migrated therefore the comment is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post-migration, these comments no longer carry anything useful for discussion and are only noise.

So, they are flag-worthy.